# Return Values from Catch

Tags: scala, try-catch

My application reads some configuration values from a file. If there are any errors in the process, I would like to set default values for those configuration parameters. What I am doing is:

```
val (param1, param2) = {
  try{
    val props = new java.util.Properties
    props.load(getClass.getResource("/myapp.properties").openStream)
    (
      props.getProperty("param1", "default1"),
      props.getProperty("param2", "default2")
    )
  }
  catch{
    case _ => ("default1", "default2")
  }
}
```

I know that what I am doing in the catch block won't work as expected if there is an exception. Is there a way to fix it? I'm using Scala 2.9

Comment: Why do you think this won't work as expected? You might want to be a bit less promiscuous in what you're catching, but apart from that it looks workable, if not idiomatic scala.

Comment: @Impredicative: I have tried changing it to `case _ => ("def1", "def2", "junk")` and the compiler didn't complain, which I interpreted as a sign that the result was probably ignored. Also, most times, one writes things that return `Unit` (like printing error messages, etc.). How will the compiler know when you want to use the result?

Comment: The compiler infers the return type. If you return different types it will most likely infer `Any`. When in doubt specify the return type explicitly: This will lead to a compile error if you return a wrong type by mistake.

Comment: @bluenote10: not in this case. No matter what I do inside the `case`, the compiler is inferring the correct types for param1 and param2. For example, if I did: `case _ => println("There was an error!")` that returns `Unit` but does not affect type inference for param1 and param2

Comment: @Eduardo: I just checked in Scala 2.10: If I change the types in the catch block to something else, the compiler infers `Any` as types in the tuple.

Comment: @bluenote10: I don't know about Scala 2.10 but in 2.9 it does not

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will work, but it opens up the possibility of a run-time error since

```
val (a,b) = whatever
```

may be called as long as `whatever` is a supertype of `Tuple2`--in particular, it could be `AnyRef` or `Any`, which is indeed what the try/catch return value will be widened to if you have sufficiently mismatching types.  You can make sure it's the right type by adding a type ascription:

```
val (a,b): (A, B) = whatever
```

and then the type checker will complain if the right-hand-side is not the correct type all the way through the try/catch.

For example:

```
val (a,b): (String, String) = try {
  ("perch", if (scala.util.Random.nextBoolean) throw new Exception else "halibut")
} catch {
  case e: Exception => ("salmon", "herring")
}
```

If you tried to add `, "cod"` after `"herring"` you'd get a compile-time error.  This assignment, if entered repeatedly, will give you a=perch and b=halibut half the time and a=salmon and b=herring the other half.

---

Addendum: in 2.9 (or below, I presume, though I haven't checked), you have to put the type ascription on the try/catch statement like so:

```
val (a,b) = (try {
  ("perch", if (scala.util.Random.nextBoolean) throw new Exception else "halibut")
} catch {
  case e: Exception => ("salmon", "herring")
}): (String, String)
```

to get the type-checking of the catch.

Comment: Have you actually tried this? I think what you return in `catch` is ignored (it is quite common to return `Unit`, for example)

Comment: Eduardo: no it is not. I just checked it in Scala 2.10. If you use: `val (param1, param2): Tuple2[String, String] = ...` you will not be able to either return ("def1", "def2", "junk") nor ("def1", 42).

Comment: @bluenote10: I cannot upgrade to 2.10, unfortunately. That is why I mentioned that I am using 2.9

Comment: @Eduardo What you return in catch is most definitely not ignored, and @RexKerr's answer is entirely correct. Try `val x = try { throw new Exception() } catch {case e : Exception => 1 }` and then inspect the value of x.

Comment: @Eduardo: you are right. I just cross-checked in 2.9 here: This only gives a compiler warning `warning: non variable type-argument String in type pattern (String, String) is unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure`

Comment: @Eduardo - Please see the update for how to do it type-safely in 2.9.